# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, es6-promise

I'm having an issue with sending a message to a Discord channel from a fetch.

I'm fetching Time Series Data from a REST API. I then want to send this data if a Discord user types a command.

Code:

```
require("dotenv").config();
const fetch = require("node-fetch");
const { Client } = require("discord.js");
const PREFIX = "!";

const getPrice = async (ticker) => {
    let result = "test";
    const request = await fetch(
      `https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY&symbol=${ticker}&interval=5min&apikey=${process.env.API_KEY}`
    );
    const response = await request.json();
    const data = await response;
    const obj = await data["Time Series (5min)"];
    result = obj[Object.keys(obj)[0]];
    return result;
};

client.on("message", (message) => {
    if (message.author.bot) return;
    if (message.content.startsWith(PREFIX)) {
      const [command, ...args] = message.content
        .trim()
        .substring(PREFIX.length)
        .split(/\s+/);
      const result = getPrice(`${command.toUpperCase()}`);
      message.channel.send(result);
    }
});
```

I get the following error:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message
```

If you take a look at the following code and replace it with a `console.log` - it works. E.g

Original

```
message.channel.send(result);
```

Replace with

```
console.log(result)
```

Then it works:

```
{
  '1. open': '119.0200',
  '2. high': '119.0200',
  '3. low': '119.0200',
  '4. close': '119.0200',
  '5. volume': '302'
}
```

I suspect it has something to do with Promises, maybe my understanding isn't up to scratch but I've read docs over and over and cannot make sense of it.

I believe the reason that `result` is empty is because by the time that method is called in the stack, the fetch has not come back with the data, and it attempts to send empty data.

How can I ensure that `message.channel.send` waits for my fetch to finish before being called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getPrice` is an async function that returns a promise. You need to await the result before you can send it:

```js
client.on("message", async (message) => {
    if (message.author.bot) return;
    if (message.content.startsWith(PREFIX)) {
      const [command, ...args] = message.content
        .trim()
        .substring(PREFIX.length)
        .split(/\s+/);
      const result = await getPrice(`${command.toUpperCase()}`);
      message.channel.send(result);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! Although, I believe (from my understanding) the getPrice resolves the promise and returns the result. I've implemented your suggestion and still running into the same error

Comment: That's weird. Async functions always return a promise though.

Comment: Ok so I managed to solve it - mostly from your suggestion. So, you were right. I needed to wait before getPrice finished. In addition, the message.channel.send method expects a string, so I put the result in template literals. Thanks again!

Comment: *"I believe ... getPrice resolves the promise"* @kenwilde not like you think. `await` is magic, where you write code like `let value = await promise` and internally it does `promise.then(value => ...)`. An `async function` will **always** return a Promise.

Comment: Thanks for the correction @Thomas, I understand now. Simply calling an async function will not resolve it, you need to use another await to .. wait for it. Thanks!